# Bash - Filtering lines according to a condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk, wc

I have a file that contains some lines as:

```
@SRR4293695.199563512 199563512 
CAAAANCATTCGTAGACGACCTGCTCTGTNGNTACCNTCAANAGATCNGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC
+SRR4293695.199563512 199563512 
A.AA<#FF)FFFFFFF<<<<FF7FFFFFF#.#<FF<#FFFF#FF<A<#FFFFFFFAFFFFFFAAAFFFFF<FFFF.
@SRR4293695.199563513 199563513 
CTAAANCATTCGTAGACGACCTGCTT
+SRR4293695.199563513 199563513 
<AAAA#FFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563514 199563514 
CCAACNTCATAGAGGGACAAGTGGCGATCNGNC
+SRR4293695.199563514 199563514 
AAAAA#<F.F<<FA.F7AA.)<FAFA..7#.#A
@SRR4293695.199563515 199563515 
TCGCGNCCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGA
+SRR4293695.199563515 199563515 
AAAAA#FFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563516 199563516 
TGACCNGGGTCCGGTGCGGAGAGCCCTTC
+SRR4293695.199563516 199563516 
AAAAA#FAFFFF<F.FFAA.F)FFFFFAF
@SRR4293695.199563517 199563517 
AAATGNTCATCGACACTTCGAACGCACT
+SRR4293695.199563517 199563517 
AA)AA#F<FFFFFFAFFFFF<)FFFAFF
@SRR4293695.199563518 199563518 
TCGTANCCAATGAGGTCTATCCGAGGCGCN
+SRR4293695.199563518 199563518 
AAAAA#<FAAFFFF.FFFFFFFA.FFFFF#
@SRR4293695.199563519 199563519 
AAAACNATTCGTAGACGNCCTGCTTNTGTNGNCACCNTNANNANNTCNGNAGAGCNCACNTCTGAACTCNAGTCAC
+SRR4293695.199563519 199563519 
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFF#FFFFFFF#FF<#F#F.FF#7#F##F##A)#A#FF<F)#AAF#<FFFFAFF<#<FFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563520 199563520 
GAAGCNGCACAGCTGGCNTTGGAGCNGANNCNGTAGNCNCNNTNNATNGNTCGGNNGAGNACACGTCTGNACTCCA
+SRR4293695.199563520 199563520 
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFF#FFFFFFF#FF##A#FFFF#F#F##<##FF#F#FFFF##FFF#FFFFFFFFF#FFFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563521 199563521 
TGGTCNGTGGGGAGTCGNCGCCTGCNTANNANTGTANGNANNANNAANANATCGNNAGANCACACGTCTNAACTCC
+SRR4293695.199563521 199563521 
AAAAA#FFFFFFFFFFF#FFFFFFF#FF##F#FFFF#F#F##A##FF#A#FFFF##<FF#FFFFFFFFF#F<FFFF
@SRR4293695.199563522 199563522 
TCGTANCCAATGAGGTCTATCCGAGGCGCN
+SRR4293695.199563522 199563522
AAAAA#<FAAFFFF.FFFFFFFA.FFFFF#
```

Then, I would like to filter these lines according to a condition :
taking in consideration the length of even lines: if that length is > 34 then that line and the preceding line must be removed.

I already did an algorithm: using a while to read all lines in the file, checking the condition and retaining only lines with length < 34. The problem is that it is taking some time.

```
inputFile=$1 
outputFile=$2

while read first_line; read second_line
  do
    lread=${#second_line}
    if [[ "$lread" -le 34 ]] ; then
        echo $first_line >> $outputFile
        echo $second_line >> $outputFile
    fi
done < $inputFile 

# This is for the last two lines
lread=${#second_line}
if [[ "$lread" -le 34 ]] ; then
  echo $first_line >> $outputFile
  echo $second_line >> $outputFile
fi
```

I was wondering if there is not another way, quicker.

The expected output:

```
@SRR4293695.199563513 199563513 
CTAAANCATTCGTAGACGACCTGCTT
+SRR4293695.199563513 199563513 
<AAAA#FFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563514 199563514 
CCAACNTCATAGAGGGACAAGTGGCGATCNGNC
+SRR4293695.199563514 199563514 
AAAAA#<F.F<<FA.F7AA.)<FAFA..7#.#A
@SRR4293695.199563515 199563515 
TCGCGNCCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGA
+SRR4293695.199563515 199563515 
AAAAA#FFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFF
@SRR4293695.199563516 199563516 
TGACCNGGGTCCGGTGCGGAGAGCCCTTC
+SRR4293695.199563516 199563516 
AAAAA#FAFFFF<F.FFAA.F)FFFFFAF
@SRR4293695.199563517 199563517 
AAATGNTCATCGACACTTCGAACGCACT
+SRR4293695.199563517 199563517 
AA)AA#F<FFFFFFAFFFFF<)FFFAFF
@SRR4293695.199563518 199563518 
TCGTANCCAATGAGGTCTATCCGAGGCGCN
+SRR4293695.199563518 199563518 
AAAAA#<FAAFFFF.FFFFFFFA.FFFFF#
@SRR4293695.199563522 199563522 
TCGTANCCAATGAGGTCTATCCGAGGCGCN
+SRR4293695.199563522 199563522
AAAAA#<FAAFFFF.FFFFFFFA.FFFFF#
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: `...somecommand... >> $outputFile` over and over is quite inefficient -- when you put that on each line separately, your script re-opens the file every time it wants to append a single line. Instead, you should open your output file just once (for example, `exec >"$outputFile"` at the top of your script will truncate the file and make all future stdout from the script redirect  to it).

Comment: That said, if you really want throughput, better to write an awk script than bash (or, if you *really* care about performance, to use a language such as Go or Julia built with it in mind).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @CharlesDuffy. And yes, I would like to write an awk script the problem is that I am not an expert yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an awk solution:

```
awk '!last { last = $0; next } length($0)<=34 { print last; print } { last = "" }' YOURFILE
```

The output is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

`sed` method:

```
sed -n 'h;n;/.\{34,\}/!{x;G;p}' inputfile > outputfile
```

1. `h;n`   The odd numbered lines go into the `h`*old* buffer, then get the `n`*ext* line.
2. The resulting even numbered lines are checked for length.  If they're *not* over 34 chars, the hold buffer is *e*`x`*change*d with the pattern space, then appended to it, (`x;G;`), so that both lines are in the pattern space, and `p`*rint*ed.